# Select interaction for each layer is not working in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have multiple layers in my OpenLayers application. I need layer based specific info Windows. Each layer will have its own select interaction. This is my problem. I do not want to add layers in one select interaction, because it is not my solution.

```
var feature1 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([21.54967, 38.70250])));
var vectorSource1 = new ol.source.Vector({ features: [feature1] });
var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource1 });
var selectClick1 = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers: [vectorLayer1]
});
selectClick1.on("select", function(e) { alert(1); })

var feature2 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([21.84967, 39.70250])));
var vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({ features: [feature2] });
var vectorLayer2 = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource2 });
var selectClick2 = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers: [vectorLayer2]
});
selectClick2.on("select", function(e) { alert(2); })


var feature3 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([21.44967, 37.70250])));
var vectorSource3 = new ol.source.Vector({ features: [feature3] });
var vectorLayer3 = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource3 });
var selectClick3 = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers: [vectorLayer3]
});
selectClick3.on("select", function(e) { alert(3); })

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer1,
    vectorLayer2,
    vectorLayer3
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([21.54967, 38.70250]),
    zoom: 8
  })
});

map.addInteraction(selectClick1);
map.addInteraction(selectClick2);
map.addInteraction(selectClick3);
```

[**The working code is here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/veung7hc/)

Comment: Please add your code in the body of the question. Links to outside resources can get lost in time.

Comment: @TomazicM I updated the code.

Comment: I dint' find any 'official' statement about that but it seems that it's possible to declare only one `select` interaction per map. If you declare mutliple ones, the last one prevails. In you JSFiddle code you are using OL3. I tried also with OL5 and it works the same. There is of course no problem in declaring single select interaction without layer specification and then checking which layer was clicked in the select event function.

Comment: see this fiddle to get the layer of the selected feature: [https://jsfiddle.net/ewxpjmkt/](https://jsfiddle.net/ewxpjmkt/)